# What is the Heroku simultaneous processes/threads limit error?

Tags: heroku, limit

I am referencing an application hosted on my free Heroku account. I think I have hit a usage limit but I don't see any errors in the web console. Does Heroku return an error when you've hit the 256 simultaneous processes/threads limit? If so, is it in my account? Where can I find it?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#process-thread-limits

Comment: Could you better describe the exact behavior you're seeing that makes you think you've hit some limit?

Comment: I don't see any errors in my code but the application isn't behaving as expected. I have reached a usage limit before with Heroku but this time, I don't see any errors.